# How to execute package with parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I have two tables:

```
students(student_id, first_name, last_name)
classes(classid, incharge_student_id)
```

I have written a package which will take `classid` as a parameter and then print the `student_id, first_name, last_name` from students table for every `incharge_student_id` of classes table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack1
AS
PROCEDURE show_info(c_id classes.classid%TYPE DEFAULT 1, show_info_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

END pack1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack1
AS
    PROCEDURE show_info 
    (   
    c_id   NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
    show_info_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
    IS
       v_first_name students.first_name%TYPE;
       v_last_name students.last_name%TYPE;
       v_students students.student_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
       SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, students.student_id
         INTO v_first_name, v_last_name, v_students
         FROM students, classes
         WHERE (classes.classid = c_id AND classes.incharge_student_id=students.student_id);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Class ID: ' || c_id);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FIRST NAME: ' || v_first_name);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST NAME: ' || v_last_name);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('student_id: ' || v_students);
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Class ID: ' || c_id || ' not found.');
    END;
END pack1;
/
```

I am getting warning message

> Package Body created with compilation errors.

I am very new to pl/sql and want to know why I am getting error message and then also want to know how will I execute a package which has a parameter.

I know how to execute normal package:

```
variable x refcursor;
exec package_name.procedure_name ( :x );
print x;
```

But how will I execute my above package with a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several errors in your code see below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack1
AS
PROCEDURE show_info(c_id classes.classid%TYPE, show_info_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

END pack1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack1
AS
    PROCEDURE show_info 
    (   
    c_id   NUMBER DEFAULT -1,
```

The specification of the c_id parameter in the body does not match the specification in the spec.  Change it to `c_id classes.classid%type default 1`, and add the `default 1` qualifier to the spec above a well.

```
    show_info_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
    IS
       v_first_name IN students.first_name%TYPE;
       v_last_name IN students.last_name%TYPE;
       v_students IN students.student_id%TYPE;
```

Remove the "IN" keywords in the variable declarations.  It's only used for parameter declarations.

```
    BEGIN
       SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, students.student_id
         INTO v_first_name, v_last_name, v_students.student_id
```

Reference v_students in you into clause not v_students.student_id

```
         FROM students, classes
         WHERE (classes.classid = c_id AND classes.incharge_student_id=students.student_id;);
```

You have an extra semicolon (`;`) inside the closing parenthesis.  Remove it.

```
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Class ID: ' || c_id);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FIRST NAME: ' || v_first_name);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST NAME: ' || v_last_name);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('student_id: ' || v_students);
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Class ID: ' || c_id || ' not found.');
    END;
END pack1;
/
```

To execute this code you just need to pass in the additional parameter, or used named parameters as mentioned by @Littlefoot though since you aren't assigning a cursor to the out parameter, there won't be anything to print.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes...and above I have made changes. But still I am getting errors like `show_info is declared in package spec and must be defined in package body` `13/5 SQL statement ignored` `14/36 invalid reference to variable v_students` `15/4 invalid identifier`. I can't understand why I am getting theses errors

Comment: Did you make both edits mention regarding c_id in the spec and body?  Also I missed an error in your INTO clause that I've now called out in the above code.

Comment: I made changes in into clause. And yes I did exactly like you said `c_id classes.classid%type default 1` and also `c_id   NUMBER DEFAULT 1,` in body. You can see the changes in my above code. Also now there's only 1 error now that `show_info is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body`

Comment: In your body you still have `c_id number` instead of `c_id classes.classid%type` they need to match exactly in both the spec and body.

Comment: Thank you sir. it's working now. But just one more help in execution. `variable info refcursor;` `exec pack1.show_info(A001, :info);` I am doing just like Littlefoot said above, but it shows that 'A001' must be declared. What am doing wrong in this sir.

Comment: based on your original code I expect `c_id` should be a number, but `A001` is not a number.  If `classes.classid` is a string then you should surround `A001` with single quotes `'A00'`  without the quotes it assumes A001 is an identifier (e.g. a function), but it hasn't been defined.  if `classes.classid` is really a number then remove the `A` and just pass in `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL*Plus, execute

```
SQL> show err
```

after compiling the package; it'll point you to the line that causes the error. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2  begin
  3    select 1 from dual;
  4  end;
  5  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/3      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL>
```

If you use a GUI, it probably contains the "Errors" tab you can examine (and get the same info).

As of calling a procedure with parameters: just include them, such as

```
variable x refcursor;
exec package_name.procedure_name (100, :x );
print x;                           ^
                                   |
                                  this is the first procedure's parameter
```

Comment: I am using sqlplus.... I am getting following errors:`9/18     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the
         following:
         constant exception <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
         char time timestamp interval date binary national character
         nchar

9/45     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..
         <an exponent (**)> || multiset`

Comment: Variables you declare shouldn't have `IN`, e.g. `v_first_name students.first_name%TYPE;`

Comment: error after removing IN`13/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`
`16/27 PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`
`16/70 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: (begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge`

Comment: `25/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "pack1" when expecting one of the following: ;`

Comment: Oracle tells you everything you need to know. Do I really have to translate every step, such as  "in line 16, position 70, there's a closed bracket which shouldn't be there"? I don't have your tables so - running your code in my database is useless (and I'm not going to create tables just to debug code for you).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IN after the variable name , and you need to run the PROCEDURE not the package also why you are defining a procedure in your case its better to make it function